# Covering $\mathbb{C}$ with open sets

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

I'm trying to cover $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ with countably many open sets $\{U_n\}$ such that the map $\phi(z) = z^2$ is injective on each of the open sets. But this seems trickier than I had imagined. Would anyone have a nice way to do this?

Here is my closest attempt: for $z = r e^{i\theta}$, the map $\phi$ essentially rotates $z$ by $\theta$ and scales by $r = |z|$. So I tried cutting the complex plane into Quadrants (like cutting a pie/pizza), and then cut each quadrant in half such that each "pie slice" had a $45$ degree angle at the origin. I tried to claim that these were the open sets, but this doesn't work; (some tinkering with them i.e. taking unions may give a covering, but $\phi$ is not injective at the 4th Quadrant slices.)

Does anyone have a nice answer to this (covering $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ with $U_i$, and not necessarily my failed attempt)? Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that there is some slice on which $\phi$ is not injective?

Comment: Surely $\operatorname{re} z >0$ and the three $90^\circ$ rotations of same will do?

Comment: @copper.hat Doesn't it overlap? For example, in the slice that is the union of the 3rd, 4th quadrant, the negative x-axis gets mapped to the positive x-axis, and the complex numbers of the 4th quadrant near the positive x-axis get mapped into the 4th quadrant.

Comment: Oh, wait.... Woops.

Comment: @Albert Yes. What is that a problem?

Comment: @copper.hat No, you're right. Can you translate your comment into an answer? I'll accept it as an answer. I thought $\phi$ was not injective for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four open sets
$\{ z | \operatorname{re} z > 0 \}$,
$\{ z | \operatorname{re} z < 0 \}$,
$\{ z | \operatorname{im} z > 0 \}$,
$\{ z | \operatorname{im} z < 0 \}$
form an open cover of $\{0\}^c$, and $f$ is injective on each one.